# Question about Converting Equivalency

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, linear-programming

I know for a linear programming problem that you can convert the condition maximise $c^T x$ for the objective function to $-$ minimise $-c^Tx$ and they mean the same thing. Here $x=x_1,x_2$ column vector by the way.

Say if you take the dual and so you end up with $-$ maximise $b^Ty$. Then surely this is equivalent to minimise $- b^Ty$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @callculus42 Thanks. I can't close this question but it's done now, cheers.